# BatchNorm1d channel size cannot match

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, batch-normalization

I get an error when trying to implement batchnorm1d in the model. The error saying **RuntimeError: running_mean should contain 32 elements not 256**, so I print out the x size after pass through fc1 which is torch.Size([60, 32, 256]). It seems that batchnorm1d will view the second column as channel size. How can I deal with this problem?

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, input_dim=512) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, 256)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(256)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        #self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.6)

        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 128)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(128)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        #self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.6)
        
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(128,32)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(32)
        self.dropout3 = nn.Dropout(0.6)

        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(32, 1)
        self.sig = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor: 
        
        x = self.relu1(self.bn1(self.fc1(x)))
        x = self.relu2(self.bn2(self.fc2(x)))
        x = self.dropout3(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.sig(self.fc4(x))
        return x
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, the second dimension is the channel dimension. As a convention, PyTorch works in a channel-first format. Layer [nn.BatchNorm1d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm1d.html) expects an input of shape `(B, C, L)` or `(B, C)`, where `C` is the `num_features` argument provided to the layer on initialization.

Comment: so what can i do now? any suggestions?

Comment: What is your input shape?

Comment: torch.Size([60, 32, 512])

Comment: What are you trying to do with this batch normalization layer? Do you want to normalize the second or the third (last) dimension of your tensor?

Comment: to normalize the output of fc1 and fc2

Comment: Which type of normalization? My question is about what dimension you want to apply the normalization operation on.

Comment: nn.BatchNorm1d (1 dimension)

Comment: `nn.Batchnorm1d` tracks one `(mu, sigma)` per channel. I am not sure what you are looking to perform. Your fc1 layer is outputting `60, 32, 256`, so the next batch norm layer should be initialized with `32` components, not `256`. Otherwise, there is a miss-shape in the input. What doe `32`, and `512` correspond to in your input tensor?

Comment: but actually, 256 is the channel size for my data, 32 correspond each video divided into 32 segments

Comment: Ah, ok. So then you should permute the 1st and 2nd dimension after your fully connected layers such that it goes into the batch norm as `(60, 256, 32)`, and not `(60, 32, 256)` as it currently does.

Comment: you mean for x input  call the function.permute(0,2,1)?

Comment: Exactly yes, do the permutation before every batch norm layer

Comment: Or you can also replace fully connected layers with a 1D conv with 1x1 kernel.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried with the permutation yet?

Comment: I tried to use the permute, but after i implement it, another error occurs RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (30720x32 and 512x256). torch.Size([60, 32, 512])
torch.Size([60, 512, 32]) this is the size of before and after using permute

Comment: Could you update your question by appending in the new code as well as this error code (in full)